# Why is Jquery not in the footer?

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to fix my javascript blocking issue, since i found the jquery.js in the header i have been trying to find a solution to move it.

i found a laborator_actions.php which contains

```
// Scripts
wp_enqueue_script( array( 'jquery', 'bootstrap', 'tweenmax', 'modernizr', 'joinable', 'isotope', 'packery' ) );
```

All of the above except for 'jquery' ARE in the FOOTER. Jquery is NOT in the footer but in the header right now. How can i move it?

refer to http://satisphy.com

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plugin/theme can [dequeue](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script) the script, and then [enqueue](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) it again, saying it must be in the footer.

Comment: Great Thanks! was looking for this for a while